Output while using terraform module and for_each
I'm struggling to get output while using module with for_each.
Module Used to create S3- https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-s3-bucket/blob/master/outputs.tf
main.tf
module "aws_s3_bucket" {
  source        = "terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws"
  version       = "4.1.2"
  create_bucket = var.create_bucket
  for_each = var.bucket
}


output "s3_bucket_arn" {
  description = "The ARN of the bucket. Will be of format arn:aws:s3:::bucketname."
  value       = module.aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_arn
}


output "s3_bucket_bucket_domain_name" {
  description = "The bucket domain name. Will be of format bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com."
  value       = module.aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_bucket_domain_name
}

variables.tf
variable "create_bucket" {
  type        = string
  description = "(Required) Environment for the deployment"
}


variable "bucket" {
  type        = set(string)
  description = "(Required) Environment for the deployment"
}

provider.tf
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "5.47.0"
    }
  }
}


provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

dev.tfvars
create_bucket = "true"

bucket   = ["s3bucket_random_8999312381", "s3bucket_random_7234023847"]

Error during plan phase:

│ Error: Unsupported attribute │ │   on s3_module.tf line 18, in
output "s3_bucket_arn": │   18:   value       =
module.aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_arn │     ├──────────────── │     │
module.aws_s3_bucket is object with 2 attributes │ │ This object does
not have an attribute named "s3_bucket_arn".
│ Error: Unsupported attribute │ │   on s3_module.tf line 23, in
output "s3_bucket_bucket_domain_name": │   23:   value       =
module.aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_bucket_domain_name │
├──────────────── │     │ module.aws_s3_bucket is object with 2
attributes │ │ This object does not have an attribute named
"s3_bucket_bucket_domain_name".

Code works fine when creating single s3 without for_each condition.
Can you please assist, I'm totally lost and unable to figure the issue.
Multiple option but no luck.

You have used for_each in the module "aws_s3_bucket" block, and so you have multiple instances of that module.
This part of the error message suggests that there are two instances of the module:
module.aws_s3_bucket is object with 2 attributes

A module call with for_each becomes an object with one attribute for each element of for_each, so the two attributes of this object will match the keys chosen in var.bucket, which in your case will yield the following two objects:

module.aws_s3_bucket["s3bucket_random_8999312381"]
module.aws_s3_bucket["s3bucket_random_7234023847"]

Because you have two instances of this module, you therefore also have two bucket ARNs and two bucket domain names, and so you'll need to decide how you want to report both of each in your output value.
One way to do it would be to combine all of this into a single output value which is a map of objects where the keys are the values from var.bucket:
output "s3_buckets" {
  value = tomap({
    for k, b in module.aws_s3_bucket : k => {
      arn         = b.s3_bucket_arn
      domain_name = b.s3_bucket_bucket_domain_name
    }
  })
}

This uses a for expression to project the attributes of module.aws_s3_bucket into a simpler data structure that only includes the two values you wanted to export in the example in your question.

Side-note: It's conventional in Terraform for an input variable of a collection type to have a plural name. Your variable describing the set of bucket keys has a collection type (set of string) and so it should ideally be named buckets (plural) rather than bucket (singular) to reflect that.
